# Angular route guard with injected handler

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Hello Stack Community,

I'm having  following class-based routing guard:

```js
export abstract class RoutingGuardByRouteEnableData {
    protected constructor(protected router: Router) { }

    canActivate(activeRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
        const isAllowedRoute: boolean = activeRoute.data?.enabled;
        if (isAllowedRoute === undefined || !isAllowedRoute) {
            return this.onDisallowAction();
        }
        return isAllowedRoute;
    }
    protected abstract onDisallowAction(): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree;
}
```

and several sub-classes that implements `onDisallowAction()` abstract function, I'll just use one example:

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RoutingGuardByRouteDataRefresh extends RoutingGuardByRouteEnableData {
    constructor(router: Router) {
        super(router);
    }

    protected onDisallowAction(): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
        window.location.replace(External404RelativeUrl);
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the usage:

```
    {
        path: 'newsletter',
        component: NotFoundComponent,
        canActivate: [RoutingGuardByRouteDataRefresh],
        data: {
            enabled: false,
            description: '',
            blurHeader: false,
            appLocation: APP_LOCATION.NEWSLETTER,
        },
    },
```

So, in general, depending on route configuration and guard implementation we provide some root path redirects, 404 redirects, external vendors redirects, e.c.t.

Personally, I think that `onDisallowAction` could be delivered as a function handler, thus delivered via injection token. To do so, I created non-abstract class that will take this handler as a parameter:

```js
export type RouteGuardType = () => Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree
export class RoutingGuardByRouteEnableData2 {
    onDisallowAction: RouteGuardType;

    constructor(protected router: Router, fn: RouteGuardType) {
        this.onDisallowAction = fn;
    }

    canActivate(activeRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
        const isAllowedRoute: boolean = activeRoute.data?.enabled;
        if (isAllowedRoute === undefined || !isAllowedRoute) {
            return this.onDisallowAction();
        }
        return isAllowedRoute;
    }
}
```

And tried to provide it's via injection tokens:

```js
export const REROUTING_FUNCTION = new InjectionToken<RouteGuardType>('Fn');
export const REROUTING_GUARD = new InjectionToken<RoutingGuardByRouteEnableData2>('Gd');
```

And use them as a factory providers in module:

```
    providers: [
        {
            provide: REROUTING_FUNCTION,
            useFactory: () => {
                return () =>  {
                    window.location.replace(External404RelativeUrl);
                    return false;
                };
            }
        },
        {
            provide: REROUTING_GUARD,
            useFactory: (r: Router, fn: RouteGuardType) => {
                return new RoutingGuardByRouteEnableData2(r, fn);
            },
            deps: [Router, REROUTING_FUNCTION]
        },
    ]
```

Unfortunately, regardless of what order of injectors declaration I'm using, I'm still getting `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'REROUTING_GUARD' before initialization`.

Guard is planned to be used in `module.routing.ts`, that is later on imported by `module.ts`, exactly as [on this Angular guide](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt5#add-the-approutingmodule). I've tried to distribute injection tokens declaration to parent module, roiting module, split them in several different ways but this seems to have no effect...

I'd appreciate any help or suggestion from your side.